# How to check values in two data frames in a row-wise manner without for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I have some problem with avoiding the usage of for-loop in my piece of code.
I have two data frames. One main data frame I am working on and the supplementary data frame that stores customer IDs that are known to be duplicated. It means, that the same customer has two (or more) IDs in the system as he may have registered more than once.

Main data frame looks like this (it has more columns that 3) : `data`

```
 index   ID    gender   ...
   0     22      M        
   1     23      F
   2     24      F
   3     33      F
   4     34      M
   5     35      F
   6     67      F
   7     68      F
```

The supplementary data frame:
`duplicatedIDs`

```
 index    primaryID    secondaryID
   0         22            34
   1         23            33
   2         35            68
```

My current code looks like this:

This is a bit to spot the row indices in the `duplicatedIDs` df where the duplicated IDs are stored:

```
n_index = [] # Row index in duplicate_df of duplicated ids
for j in range(1,len(duplicatedIDs['primaryID'])): 
    if ( (duplicatedIDs['primaryID'][j] in ( 
      data['ID'].values)) & (duplicatedIDs['secondaryID'] [j] in (data['ID'].values))):
        n_index.append(j);
```

The code snippet to replace duplicated IDs. I am using `secondaryID` as the main one:

```
for j in n_index: 
    if ( (duplicatedIDs['primaryID'][j] in (data['ID'].values)) & (duplicatedIDs['secondaryID'][j] in (data['ID'].values))):
         data.loc[data['ID'] == duplicatedIDs['primaryID'][j], 'ID'] = duplicatedIDs['secondaryID'][j]
```

I want to avoid the for-loop as the `duplicatedIDs` df has tens of thousands of rows and it takes some time to complete. I tried to do something with `np.select` or `np.where`, but I cannot make that they operate on the same row-level somehow.

The main data frame after manipulation should look like this:

```
 index   ID    gender   ...
   0     34      M        
   1     33      F
   2     24      F
   3     33      F
   4     34      M
   5     68      F
   6     67      F
   7     68      F
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get rid of the secondary IDs that are in `duplicatedIDs `?

Comment: No. I know which IDs are duplicated. Because duplicatedID are stored in `duplicatedIDs` data frame in a row-wise manner. So ID = 22 and ID = 33 are known duplicates. Therefore I want to change all `primaryID` to `secondaryID` in my main data frame `data`. I added the look of `data` df after the manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would create a dictionary from `duplicatedIDs` `primaryID` and `secondaryID`, and then use `df.replace`:

```
data.replace({'ID':dict(duplicatedIDs[['primaryID', 'secondaryID']].values)})

   index  ID gender
0      0  34      M
1      1  33      F
2      2  24      F
3      3  33      F
4      4  34      M
5      5  68      F
6      6  67      F
7      7  68      F
```

**Explanation:**

The dictionary that gets created using `dict(duplicatedIDs[['primaryID', 'secondaryID']].values)` looks like:

```
 {22: 34, 23: 33, 35: 68}
```

Then, using the nested dictionary syntax of [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), you change the values of your known duplicates to their `secondaryID` values.

Comment: I tried you answer, but i got an error:
`ValueError: Replacement not allowed with overlapping keys and values`. Can it be caused by the fact that I can have multiple instances of the same `ID` in my `data` df? Or it may be caused by the fact the there are instances in `duplicatedIDs` like `{22:34}` and `{34:125}`?

Comment: I think the latter, df.replace doesn’t know which to replace first, I guess